# Variable en xamarin que solo se inicialize cuando entro a la aplicación

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Estoy creando una aplicación en Xamarin Android, pero necesito saber donde poner una variable que solo se incialize en cero cuando se ingresa a la aplicación, cuando se este dentro de la aplicación que no se vuelva a inicializar hasta que salga y vuelva a entrrar.

Answer (score 1):

Estimado, podrías utilizar las variables de `SharedPreferences`. Las cuales son variables globales para toda tu aplicación:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Y setearla en cero en un Splash Screen:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/creating_a_splash_screen/

Espero ser de ayuda :)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes "inicializar" esa variable en varios sitios dependiendo de la plataforma y de la complejidad de la app. En el caso de Android, puedes extender la clase [Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html), que es el punto de entrada de todas las apps y definir ahí esa variable. Puedes definirla de forma estática y consultarla desde cualquier sitio:

```
public class MyApp : Application
{
       //
       // para consultarla, usa MyApp.MyCounter
       // 
       public static int MyCounter { get; set; }

       public MyApp(IntPtr handle, global::Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transer)
              :base(handle, transer)
      {
      }

      public override void OnCreate()
      {
          base.OnCreate();
      }
}
```

Puedes ver más info en este post [forums xamarin Application](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/47812/activity-vs-application)

Answer (score 0):

Segun las buenas practicas de Android. 
si quieres instanciar una variable como lo comentas, lo correcto seria hacerlo en la carpeta de **Assest**. en un Archivo xml.
dentro de este folder se agregan archivos que cuando el paquete .APK es generado conservan sus nombres y características.